# Is it possible to keep my Nix packages in sync across machines not running NixOS?

Tags: nix

I know with NixOS, you can simply copy over the `configuration.nix` file to sync your OS state including installed packages between machines.

Is it possible then, to do the same using Nix the package manager on a non-NixOS OS to sync only the installed packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please note, that at least since 30.03.2017 (corresponding to 17.03 Nix/NixOS channel/release), as far as I understand the official, modern, supported and suggested solution is to use the so called *overlays*.

**See [the chapter titled "Overlays"](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-overlays) in the nixpkgs manual** for a nice guide on how to use the new approach.

As a short summary: you can put any number of files with *.nix* extension in `$HOME/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/` directory. They will be processed in alphabetical order, and each one can modify the set of available Nix packages. Each of the files must be written as in the following pattern:

```
self: super:
{
  boost = super.boost.override {
    python = self.python3;
  };
  rr = super.callPackage ./pkgs/rr {
    stdenv = self.stdenv_32bit;
  };
}
```

- The `super` set corresponds to the "old" set of packages (before the overlay was applied). If you want to refer to the old version of a package (as in `boost` above), or `callPackage`, you should reference it via `super`.
- The `self` set corresponds to the eventual, "future" set of packages, representing the final result after all overlays are applied. (Note: don't be scared when sometimes using them might get rejected by Nix, as it would result in infinite recursion. Probably you should rather just use `super` in those cases instead.)

<sub>Note: with the above changes, the solution I mention below in the original answer seems "deprecated" now — I believe it should still work as of April 2017, but I have no idea for how long. It appears [marked as "obsolete" in the nixpkgs repository](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/17.03/pkgs/top-level/impure.nix#L31).</sub>

---

---

*Old answer, before 17.03:*

Assuming you want to synchronize apps *per-user* (as non-NixOS Nix keeps apps visible [on per-user basis, not system-wide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33808176/98528), as far as I know), it *is* possible to do it declaratively. It's just not well advertised in the manual — though it seems quite popular among long-time Nixers!

You must create a text file at: `$HOME/.nixpkgs/config.nix` — e.g.:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.nixpkgs
$ $EDITOR ~/.nixpkgs/config.nix
```

then enter the following contents:

```
{
  packageOverrides = defaultPkgs: with defaultPkgs; {
    home = with pkgs; buildEnv {
      name = "home";
      paths = [
        nethack mc pstree #...your favourite pkgs here...
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

Then you should be able to install all listed packages with:

```
$ nix-env -i home
or:
$ nix-env -iA nixos.home   # *much* faster than above
```

In `paths` you can put stuff in a similar way like in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` on NixOS. Also, `home` is actually a "fake package" here. You can add more custom package definitions beside it, and then include them your "paths".

<sub>*(Side note: I'm hoping to write a blog post with what I learned on how exactly this works, and also showing how to extend it with more customizations. I'll try to remember to link it here if I succeed.)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Wish it was better documented in the official manual for beginners like myself.

Comment: Blog post please! :)

Comment: @tlo WILCO :) It's still brewing, I'm a slow writer. By the way, taking the opportunity ― would you be more interested in reading on *"how to do more customizations"* earlier (i.e. usage), or *"how exactly this works"* (i.e. internals)? I'm at a branching point with how to plan the series, so it's a perfect moment to influence it :)

Comment: @akavel I would prefer "how exactly this works", preferably with some examples. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the 'obsolete' comment applies to the non-XDG path `~/.nixpgks`, not to `~/.config/nixpkgs`.